# How to use chmod function in my project

Tags: php, apache

I am a rookie in PHP , i got an error 500 Internal Server Error when i test a `POST` .

I try to find out what's the issue happen and i find the answer that may be is permissions .

So i try to use `chmod` function ,i don't know it's correct or wrong , because i still got the error  500 Internal error.

Any one can teach me how to set the function correct ?
Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Here is my structure:
[image]

i use the code like this , is this correct ?

```
chmod('../v1/index.php', 0644);
```

Comment: Tip: Keep in mind that your are always `www-data` if you are running a script from a web-browser. If you are running from command line you are a diff. user.

Comment: Start here please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12772851/476

Comment: I think that it is in www folder , i can open other projects only HTML example.

Comment: thanks , i solved my issue , thanks for responding.